# cant install (or see) setup.sh from command prompt, even though i can see it in file viewer

Tags: command-line, software-installation

i am very very new to linux, and also very very not smart in general, and i could use some help with this.  i want to install sonic 3 air but it wont work when i do the thing with the setup file, i have no idea what im talking about but here

[

> some of the commands ive tried so far and an example
> ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqZC9.png)

probably a really simple/obvious question, im just really new to using linux in general sorry

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting to show all the commands run and their output. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; no clues as to what software you're using, but your switching to root user before running it (instead of using `sudo`) looks to me like it'll create more problems than it'll solve (*you risk not being able to access anything when using your normal account, making it unable to access GUI/graphics for some releases but we don't know yours*) so are you sure you're following instructions correctly?

Comment: Looks like missing executable bit on `setup.sh`. Try `ls -l` to check which bits are set. Use `chmod +x setup.sh` to make it executable and after that you'll be able to run `./setup.sh`. Before adding executable bit it's a good practice to open the file in text editor (ie. gedit) to check if it's not malicious and doesn't do anything you wouldn't like to be done.

Also you shouldn't need `sudo` here.

Comment: Alright, i see that i shouldnt use sudo now. I didnt know that before, and im not quite sure why i started doing that in the first place, lol. I tried doing chmod +x setup.sh, then running ./setup.sh, but i still get nothing, the prompt returns absolutely nothing after i execute either of those. Is there some kind of package i need to get? i feel like im missing something really basic

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have such behaviour is that you switched to user `root`.  Therefore, the default libraries changed to the ones of `root` instead of the ones of `gr3`.  This results in the message `No such file or directory`.

To solve:

1. Do not use `sudo -s`
2. Use `sudo ./setup.sh` from the very same start point.

Answer (score 0):

> can't install (or see) setup.sh

that setup is work properly but the script is not set to appearing any messages.

**How to install Sonic 3 A.I.R from the Manual.pdf**

1. run `bash ./setup_linux.sh` This will add a "Sonic 3 A.I.R." launcher link to the applications / start menu. Don,t use `sudo -s`.
2. Add the Sonic 3 & Knuckles ROM on you Steam.
3. You can start the sonic3air_linux executable directly in main installation directory, run `./sonic3air_linux`

Hope this helps.